# angularjs html component configuration

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

I am implementing a simple grid component in angularjs. I prefer html configuration over javascript because that way view code and logic code is separated.

For example,

```
<my-grid> 
     <my-column title="Name" field"name"></column>
     <my-column title="Age" field"age"></column>
 </my-grid>
```

I have created a my-column component that requires a my-grid component. When the controller is initialized it inspects the element and calls addColumn function of my-grid.

I need to properly initialize all my-column before finally building the grid. Is there any hook after all nested controllers are initialized ($onInit function is called) ?

If not should I change my design what is the angularjs appropriate design ?

Comment: Do you now about the number of `my-column` components in `my-grid`? If yes, you could probably hide the grid initially, as long as all columns called `$onInit` and perform some kind of notification to the parent component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used scipper's recommendation with a little tweak.

The my-grid is initially on Initializing state.

Each sub component (for example my-column) in each $onInit notifies my-grid of it's presence and my-grid increments a counter.

When a sub component is finished or fails notifies again my-grid with the result
and the counter is decremented.

When this counter reaches zero, all sub components are initialized. This is checked both on $postLink and whenever a sub component is finishes. The $postLink is required in case there are no sub components at all.

While the grid is initializing, a nice loading bar is displayed.